# Javascript split text string to fit within div element pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been using overflow scroll to display the text. I realize that the overflow property can detect when the data is larger than will fit. 
I need to fill one div element, then another, and so on until all the data is set within pages. The breaks can't break a word.
Only one page/div will be display: block; and the rest will be display: none;

What is the best way to allow data to be displayed on multiple div pages?

Comment: There is a great answer here which should help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828635/how-can-you-tell-when-a-div-is-full-of-text. Using the suggestion in this answer you can tell when the div is 'overflowing' and then use `lastIndexOf` to find where the last whitespace character was and split there.

Answer (score 0):

Why not you use css for this purpose?

```
<div style="height:50px; width:50px; overflow:hidden">testing</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ali is right in using CSS to address this, but you should use the CSS word-wrap property to easily acheive your desired effect with the overflow content, as Ali's example edited below.

```
<div style="height:auto; min-height:50px; width:50px; word-wrap:break-word;">testing<div>
```

The word-wrap property is now supported in all major browsers.

Also as shown above, if you want to be sure that all the text shows as well as wraps in the correct place, then change your height CSS to 'height:auto; min-height:50px;'. This will allow the div to expand in height to show any overflow that would normally be hidden just defining a fixed height, while retaining the preferred size of 50px if possible, and retaining the desired word wrap not breaking a word in the middle.

The only exception where this will not work, is if a word is so long as to be longer than the width of the containing div, in which case it will break the long word at the last character that will fit on the line before continuing the word on the next line.

It's got to be an awfully long word though to run into this. If you use auto for the width property as done in the example with the height, it will fix the word break problem by allowing the width of the div to change, although in page layout it is usually more important to constrain a width much more than a height.